# How to add animation in the clippath of svg

Tags: svg

I'm learning how to use svg clippath. And I know how to use the static clippath.

```html
<svg width="500" height="150">
    <clipPath id="circle">
     <circle cx=50 cy=50 r=50></circle>
    </clipPath>
    <circle cx=50 cy=50 r=50></circle>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="15"
          style="stroke: #ff0000; fill: none;" clip-path='url(#circle)'>
    </rect>
</svg>
```

there I can get a clip rect.
[code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Z7O.png)

but when I try to add an animation, the rect could out of the clippath.

```html
<svg width="500" height="150">
    <clipPath id="circle">
     <circle cx=50 cy=50 r=50></circle>
    </clipPath>
    <circle cx=50 cy=50 r=50></circle>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="15"
          style="stroke: #ff0000; fill: none;" clip-path='url(#circle)'>
        <animateMotion
                path="M10,50 q60,50 100,0 q60,-50 100,0"
                begin="0s" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"
                rotate="auto"
               ></animateMotion>
    </rect>
</svg>
```

[The rect is out of clippath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjIbL.png)

what I need is when the rect is out of clippath, it could not be seen any more. The clippath is not allow to move.

So how to get the rectangle in motion to remain in the clippath？

Answer (score 1):

You put the clipped rect in a group and you apply the animation to the group like so:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 300">
    <clipPath id="circle">
     <circle cx=50 cy=50 r=50>       
     </circle>
    </clipPath>
    <g>
    <circle cx=50 cy=50 r=50></circle>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="15"
          style="stroke: #ff0000; fill: none;" clip-path='url(#circle)'>
       
    </rect>
    
     <animateMotion
                path="M10,50 q60,50 100,0 q60,-50 100,0"
                begin="0s" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"
                rotate="auto"
               ></animateMotion>
    </g>
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting that his question *has now been revised*.

> My question is how to not show the rectangle when it moves outside the clippath?

In this case you put the animated rect in a group and you clip the group like so:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 150">
    <clipPath id="circle">
     <circle cx=50 cy=50 r=50></circle>
    </clipPath>
  <g clip-path='url(#circle)'>
    <circle cx=50 cy=50 r=50></circle>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="15"
          style="stroke: #ff0000; fill: none;" >
        <animateMotion
                path="M10,50 q60,50 100,0 q60,-50 100,0"
                begin="0s" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"
                rotate="auto"
               ></animateMotion>
    </rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! It was my description of the problem that was inadequate and has now been revised. My question is how to not show the rectangle when it moves outside the clippath?